# Wraps and Loops—Which Sequences are Admissible?

Tags: mathematics, visual, geometry

If you take a non-intersecting closed loop on a torus (that is to say, a path  which ends where it starts and does not cross over itself, drawn inside a square whose edges "wrap" left to right and top to bottom), you can use it to infinitely tile the plane in a lined pattern:

[image]
*Example loop (w/ basepoint), and the corresponding tiling in the plane*

Moreover, if we take our basepoint and follow the path produced on the plane diagram until we hit a basepoint once again, we find that we move through a series of tiles, perhaps not ending up where we started:

[image]
*Extracting the arrow sequence from the loop (w/ given basepoint and travel direction)*

In this way, we say that the sequence ↑←↓↓←↑→↓ is *admissible*. However, not all sequences of arrows can be produced this way; a diagram producing the sequence simply cannot be drawn. Those sequences are called *inadmissible*. Can you find an effective means for determining if a provided sequence is admissible or inadmissible?

Here are some example cases to get you started (which your algorithm should correctly label as admissible or inadmissible):

1. ↓←→↓↑→←↓
2. ↑↑↑→↑←
3. ↑↑↓→←↑→↑→

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: As a reference I've written a super dumb brute force algo which just tries all possible permutations of the horizontal and vertical boundary crossings.

Here are the results for the four test cases:

> [image]

End of UPDATE.

Note: The core of the algorithm is still rather sketchy, so this may be regarded as a partial answer.

Sketch of decision "algorithm":

> ```
>      input: ULDDLURD
>      1) form pairs, wrapping around: UL,LD,DD,DL,LU,UR,RD,DU
>      2) discard direction: UL,LD,UU,RU,DR,LD,UL,UD
>      if both UU and LL occur return FALSE
>      pool U,D->V and L,R->H and for each try to find an
>          ordering such that
>      for all pairs made in (1,2) the following is satisfied
>      if there are two pairs U1L1,U2L2 then U1<U2 <=> L1<L2
>          and similar for DR
>      if there are two pairs L1D1,L2D2 then L1<L2 <=> D1>D2
>          and similar for RU
>      if there are two pairs U1U2,U2U3 then U1<U2 <=> U2<U3
>          and similar for LL
>      for any pair U1D1 (or D1U1) all V such that U1<V<D1 are
>          also part of a UD (or DU) pair
>          and similar for LR (or RL)
>      for any two pairs U1L1,L2D2 we have L2>L1
>          and similar for R1U1,U2L2, for R1U1,U2U3,
>          for U1U3,U2L2, for U1L1,L2L3 and for L1L3,L2D2
>      for any two pairs D1R1,R2U2 we have R2<R1
>          and similar for L1D1,D2R2, for L1D1,U3U2,
>          for U3U1,D2R2, for D1R1,R3R2 and for R3R1,R2U2
>      return TRUE if such two orderings exists otherwise
>          return FALSE
> ```

Remarks:

> 1. The orderings in the algorithm, of course, directly correspond to the (spatial) order of crossings along tile boundaries
>  
>   2. The rules spelt out are just a rundown of what needs to hold so no segments cross
>  
>   3. Admittedly, the actual algorithmic test for/construction of the orderings is a challenge in itself.

Comment: The first thing I don't understand is where the pairs from "discard direction" are coming from, or what "pool U,D->V and L,R->H" mean. I'll give you the same test case (not already elaborated by diagrammatic example) that I gave Vicky: What does your algorithm say about ↓←→↓↑→←↓? Is it admissible or inadmissible?

Comment: @Feryll, U,D->V means up,down->vertical. They naturally pool because they both are crossings of the horizontal tile boundary. Similarly, if we discard direction then for example UL and RD are the same, they describe the same class of trajectories backward or forward. I'm pretty sure algo says no to your new example because a pair of orderings with the necessary properties does not exist. I'll try and rephrase a bit to hopefully make things a bit clearer.

Comment: Here are another couple of test cases, if you're interested: ↑↑↑→↑← and ↑↑↓→←↑→↑→

Comment: @Feryll Actually, I'm beginning to think that I have only reformulated but not really solved the problem...

Comment: If you can describe an algorithm that at least terminates in finite time on every input and correctly answers "admissible" or "inadmissible," then I would probably wind up accepting the answer. However, ideally I would like either a polynomial time solution, or a proof that the problem is NP-hard.

Comment: I really feel like I must be missing something, because this doesn't seem anywhere near NP-hard to me.... :-(

Comment: OMG hang on. I think I've got what you're getting at now. Are you saying that for a given sequence we have to find a set of points along the edges / connecting lines between them, such that the sequence would become admissible and all the other constraints (lines not crossing etc) that you gave in your question would also be met? So as input to the algorithm we have NOTHING other than the sequence? I thought you meant we have the sequence *and* a given set of lines on tiles.

Comment: And if I am correct in my new understanding, you are saying that *input* is the arrow sequence and *output* is either nothing (inadmissible) or a set of pairs of points on the edge of the square plus a start point. If this is the case, please can you edit the question to clarify this? As originally written, I interpreted the question as input: arrow sequence, set of pairs of points; output: start point.

Comment: @Vicky Yes, that is all correct. It is input: arrow sequence; output: yes/no.

Comment: @Feryll I've written a brute-force solver (appalling complexity) I've updated the post with the answers to the four test cases. Could you please check them? And do you happen to have more test cases?

Comment: Your answers to the test cases are correct. Since part of this puzzle was about discovering the discrete combinatorics problem beneath the hood in the first place (which, together with some partial results, is only as far as I myself have gotten), I think I'll go ahead and accept your answer in about a week if interest dies down in the problem. In the meantime, I think I'll write my own solver to further my analysis of the puzzle... At any rate, I don't have any more interesting inadmissible examples.

Comment: @Feryll, yeah, this feels like a combinatorial problem that should admit (heh) an elegant solution. But combinatorial problems are also notorious of its ability to hide its complexity. So hopefully there is a more elegant answer coming. Good problem! (and good answer again, loopy!)

Comment: I've made a sequel to this problem now, with more examples; hope you're interested!